# Laravel tymon/jwt-auth, which version can I use?

Tags: laravel, jwt

I try to use JWT authentication for my own api,

but when I've done a search, I found some tutorials use tymon/jwt-auth:0.5

and others use tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.0

and I know that tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.0 is still beta?

what is the best version to use?

Comment: use the version constraint 0.5.*

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use 1.0.0 release candidates if you know what you're doing (meaning you can figure it out by looking at the source code) since the docs for 1.0 arent out yet. If not, go with the 0.5.* version

Answer (score 0):

I'm from 2019, and all people use version `1.0.0-rc.4.1` for Laravel 5.8.

*Yes, it is 'release candidate 4.1', but it works and it's stable.*